# Why isn't Django actually writing changes to test db

Tags: django

In my settings.py I have this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'foo',
    'USER': 'foo',
    'PASSWORD': 'foo',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    },
}
```

I've ran this SQL on my db:

```
GRANT ALL ON test_foo.* TO 'foo'@'localhost';
```

I've distilled what I'm trying to figure out with my test to this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_create_user(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@bla.net', password='top_secret')
        user.save()
        user = User.objects.get(username="jacob")
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

When I run the test and hit the break point, I query the auth_user table in test_foo and it is empty.

Why is this?  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django's `TestCase` class makes use of database transactions (if the database supports it) to speed up tests.

This means that within a test method, any database modifications is only visible to that test and is not committed to the database. You won't be able to inspect the changes using an external tool.

If you need tests to commit changes to the test database, you can extend `TransactionTestCase` instead. E.g.

```
class UserTestCase(TransactionTestCase):

    def test_create_user(self):
        # any database changes will be visible in the test database
        ....
```

At the end of each `TransactionTestCase` test, the database is reset to a known state. Do note that this will make your unit tests slower. Once again, only databases that support transactions (e.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL+InnoDB) will exhibit this behavior.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase for more information.

Comment: I tested it and that is what was going happening.  TY!

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.

The default database name starts with `test_`, per the docs linked above.

Comment: "When I run the test and hit the break point, I query the auth_user table in test_foo"

The name of the db is foo, I'm seeing test_foo get created and am using that db when I query the auth_user table.  So unfortunately, this does not solve the mystery.  TY for your time though.